# Why golang don't iterate correctly in my for loop with range?

Tags: go, goroutine

I am confused why the following code does not print out iterated value.

```
test:= []int{0,1,2,3,4}
for i,v := range test{
  go func(){
    fmt.Println(i,v)
  }
}
```

What I think is that it should print out

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3 
4 4
```

But instead, it printed out

```
4 4
4 4
4 4
4 4
4 4
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your goroutines don't capture the current value of the variables `i` and `v`, but rather they reference the variables themselves.  In this case, the 5 spawned goroutines did not get scheduled until the for loop finished, so all printed out the last values of `i` and `v`.

If you want to capture the current values of some variables for the gouroutine, you could modify the code to read something like the following:

```
go func(i, v int){
    fmt.Println(i,v)
}(i, v)
```

Now each gouroutine has its own copy of the variables holding the value at the time it was spawned.

Comment: Oh Thanks, James! I was trying to fix it for almost an hour.
My problem is solved.